# What is Debian equivalent of RPM package perl-ExtUtils-Embed?

Tags: debian, perl

I need to install some SW on Debian. This SW requires perl-ExtUtils-Embed in a installation guide made for RedHat based systems (CentOS in my case).

What should I install on Debian to get all what is got by installing perl-ExtUtils-Embed on CentOS?

Comment: What is this software that it doesn't correctly pull in the packages it requires during installing?

Comment: You can try `libperl-dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a RPM based system:

```
$ repoquery -l perl-ExtUtils-Embed
```

lists the files in the package:

```
/usr/share/man/man3/ExtUtils::Embed.3pm.gz
/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/Embed.pm
```

Therefore, you're looking for `Embed.pm`.

On Ubuntu (which I believe is close enough to Debian in this case):

```
$ apt-file search Embed.pm
```

searches for a packages that provides the given file, which returns:

```
perl-modules: /usr/share/perl/5.18.2/ExtUtils/Embed.pm
```

Therefore, I believe you need to install `perl-modules`.

Comment: Yes, Debian gives the same result.

Comment: `perl` depends on `perl-modules` (those are the core `perl` modules, shipped with `perl`. They are in a separate package because they are architecture independent), so if you have `perl`, you have `perl-modules` and `ExtUtils::Embed`.

Comment: Problem solved. It was perl-modules. Thanks everybody.